# What is this yellow highlight?

Tags: support, google, google-chrome

I've just noticed it today for the first time. Looks like if I come from google by searching for a specific text, that text gets highlighted (but also other related blocks)..

[image]

**Update**:
Looks like it's a google thing and I don't like this:

[image]

Clicking from within that box shows highlighing:

[image]

Comment: I haven't seen this before, and indeed can't see it when  I navigate directly to [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38760773/3270037). Have you got the link you navigated to it from? The closest I could get is putting that whole section into the Find box in browser, which highlights finds.

Comment: Looks like this happens when you come from google by clicking on featured snippets.. must be chrome only? Updated the question..

Comment: Looks like you encountered this: https://www.google.com/amp/s/9to5google.com/2019/08/26/google-search-highlight-website-content/amp/

Comment: They've also made it so accepted answers have indented direct links underneath questions in the search results. It shows up a little fubared (half the title is cut off), but it's definitely new.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Google is conducting tests (with a small percentage of users) [highlighting search results in the page](https://www.google.com/amp/s/9to5google.com/2019/08/26/google-search-highlight-website-content/amp/).

> If you recently made a search on Google and noticed that the website from that result had text highlighted, you might be a part of a test the company has ongoing. Around 5% of search results are highlighting text on a website you visit.

This would only work in Chrome, using a [Google-proposed feature called *Scroll to Text Fragment*](https://wicg.github.io/ScrollToTextFragment/).

This is not anything special to Stack Overflow.